# Pressure wave like colliding masses?

Tags: pressure, momentum, collision

Assume I have a very narrow beam of a pressure wave travelling along one axis of a plane, say the x-axis, and another very narrow beam of a pressure wave travelling along another axis, say the y-axis.

The directions of each travelling pressure wave are such that they will intersect at the origin.

Will a collision, like two colliding billiard balls, occur and produce a travelling pressure wave that has both x and y components?

Comment: Probably relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96192/is-it-possible-to-create-an-audible-sound-source-in-mid-air-by-intersecting-ultr